# When I use electron-builder to package an NSIS program, I get: Fatal error: Unable to parse version string for FileVersion

Tags: node.js, electron

Electron-Builder Version: 22.14.5

Node Version: v16.13.1

Electron Version: 16.0.6

Electron Type (current, beta, nightly): current

Not using electron-updater

Target: nsis

Here is the console log.

```sh
Compilation succeeded.
  • electron-builder  version=22.14.5 os=5.10.89-1-MANJARO
  • loaded configuration  file=/home/aszswaz/document/notebook/code-example/webpack-electron-vue/config/electron-builder-win.js
  • Specified application directory equals to project dir — superfluous or wrong configuration  appDirectory=./
  • writing effective config  file=dist/electron-builder/builder-effective-config.yaml
  • skipped dependencies rebuild  reason=npmRebuild is set to false
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=v16.0.6 appOutDir=dist/electron-builder/win-unpacked
  • asar usage is disabled — this is strongly not recommended  solution=enable asar and use asarUnpack to unpack files that must be externally available
  • asar usage is disabled — this is strongly not recommended  solution=enable asar and use asarUnpack to unpack files that must be externally available
  ⨯ cannot execute  cause=exit status 1
                    errorOut=Fatal error: Unable to parse version string for FileVersion
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0032FE94 00000000): stub

                    command=wine /home/aszswaz/.cache/electron-builder/winCodeSign/winCodeSign-2.6.0/rcedit-ia32.exe /home/aszswaz/document/notebook/code-example/webpack-electron-vue/dist/electron-builder/win-unpacked/hanna.exe --set-version-string FileDescription hanna --set-version-string ProductName hanna --set-version-string LegalCopyright aszswaz --set-file-version v1.0.0 --set-product-version 1.0.0.0 --set-version-string InternalName hanna --set-version-string OriginalFilename '' --set-version-string CompanyName aszswaz --set-icon /home/aszswaz/document/notebook/code-example/webpack-electron-vue/public/icon.ico
                    workingDir=
```

This is the config file used.

```js
module.exports = {
    appId: "cn.aszswaz.demo.webpack-electron-vue",
    productName: "hanna",
    copyright: "aszswaz",
    asar: false,
    files: [
        "dist/app/*",
        "!**/node_modules/vue/*",
        "!**/node_modules/vue-router/*"
    ],
    artifactName: "${productName}-${arch}-${version}.${ext}",
    directories: {
        app: "./",
        output: "./dist/electron-builder"
    },
    win: {
        target: "nsis",
        icon: "public/icon.ico"
    },
    nsis: {
        oneClick: false,
        perMachine: true,
        allowToChangeInstallationDirectory: true
    },
    npmRebuild: false,
    buildVersion: "v1.0.0",
    electronCompile: false,
    electronDownload: {
        version: "16.0.6",
        platform: "win32",
        arch: "x64",
        cache: process.cwd() + "/cache"
    },
    electronVersion: "v16.0.6"
}
```

What is the reason for this error? How can I fix this error?